# How to best store data locally - useMutation vs writeQuery

Tags: next.js, graphql, apollo-client, react-apollo, react-apollo-hooks

I'm using Apollo Client 3 for my NextJS project.

What I need to do is save nested data **locally**. I first implemented a function with reactive variables but from my experience, it's not the best approach when dealing with nested data.

What I found out work best so far is the `client.writeQuery({ query: MUTATION, data: { ...data } )` method.

This approach seems to work out of the box, you don't even need to add the type definitions for the data when you init ApolloClient, and all the useQuery watches the data and it is displayed correctly.

**Display Group Mutation**

```
const DISPLAY_GROUP_MUTATION = gql`
mutation UpdateDisplayGroup {
    displayGroup @client {
        id
        alias
        name
        display {
            id
            alias
            name
            show
            options {
                id
                type
                alias
                value
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

**Display Group Mutation** - Called when pressing a button

```
client.writeQuery({
    query: DISPLAY_GROUP_MUTATION,
    data: {
        displayGroup: {
            id: 'display-group',
            alias: 'display-group',
            name: 'Display Group',
            display: [
                {
                    id: 'display-1',
                    alias: 'display-1',
                    name: 'Display 1',
                    show: true,
                    options: [
                        {
                            id: 'display-1-option-1',
                            type: 'toggler',
                            alias: 'option-1',
                            value: true
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    id: 'display-2',
                    alias: 'display-2',
                    name: 'Display 2',
                    show: true,
                    options: [
                        {
                            id: 'display-2-option-1',
                            type: 'toggler',
                            alias: 'option-1',
                            value: true
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'display-2-option-2',
                            type: 'radio',
                            alias: 'text-size',
                            value: 'text-lg'
                        },
                        {
                            id: 'display-2-option-text-color',
                            type: 'color',
                            alias: 'text-color',
                            value: '#febbcb'
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    }
})
```

Now I tried the `useMutation` method but without any success and it seems to be more complicated to achieve the same result.

**Display Group mutation for useMutation**

```
const DISPLAY_GROUP_MUTATION_2 = gql`
mutation UpdateDisplayGroup($alias: String!, $name: String!, $id: ID!) {
    displayGroup @client {
        id
        alias
        name
    }
}`
```

**useMutation inisiation**

```
const [updateDisplayGroup, { loading, error }] = useMutation(DISPLAY_GROUP_MUTATION_2 })
```

**useMutation** - Called when pressing a button

```
        updateDisplayGroup({
        variables: {
            id: 'display-group',
            alias: 'display-group',
            name: 'Display Group useMutation'
        }
    })
```

Although I don't get any errors, the data is not tuched. And I do have type defs added when initiating ApolloClient

```
const typeDefs = gql`
type DisplayGroup {
    id: Int!
    alias: ID!
    name: String
    display: [Display]
}

type Display {
    id: Int!
    alias: ID!
    name: String
    show: Boolean
    options: [Option]
}

type Option {
    id: Int!
    alias: ID!
    value: String
    type: String
}

# the schema allows the following query:
type Query {
    displayGroup: [DisplayGroup]
}

# this schema allows the following mutation:
type Mutation {
    displayGroup(id: Int!): DisplayGroup
}`
```

Why is the useMutation approach not successful?
Is my writeQuery approach the absolute smoothest way to store data locally?
Is there something else I'm missing here?

Comment: You need to create a type policy for that local mutation, and you can modify the cache there. 

https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/local-state/managing-state-with-field-policies#modifying

Comment: I ended up using writeQuery successfully after adding __typename to each object!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the full advantage of Apollo Client, the __typename needs to be added to each object for the mutation.

That will enable Apollo Client to correctly organize the data, and you will then be able to use `client.readFragment` and `client.writeFragment` to manipulate data with a specific ID.